# How to give "apache" rights to run "svn update"

Tags: apache-http-server, svn

I want to fire "svn update" command from a php script , the user for which is "apache".
How can I assign permissions to apache user to execute "svn update" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a command in the sudoers file, and then use `sudo -u user-who-owns-svn-repo svn update` in your PHP script.

The changes to `/etc/sudores` would be similar to:

```
Cmnd_Alias      SVN = /usr/local/bin/svn
apache          ALL=(ALL,!root,!#0) NOPASSWD: SVN
```

See the [Sudoers manual](http://www.courtesan.com/sudo/man/sudoers.html) for more info.

If you want tighter controls, make shell scripts that have the specific SVN commands and only allow Apache access to those. For example:

File `/path/to/my/project/update.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
svn update /path/to/my/project/svn-files
```

File `/etc/sudores`:

```
Cmnd_Alias      SVN = /path/to/my/project/update.sh
apache          ALL=(ALL,!root,!#0) NOPASSWD: SVN
```

(and don't forget to `chmod +x path/to/my/project/update.sh`)

Comment: Hi Josh, hope you are still around, thanks so much, this saved my day (week really!).

Comment: I am still around and pleased that my answer helped you @mario!